# How to send discord custom emoji from any server using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord, pycord

How do I send custom emoji using discord.py that is from another server?

Here is what I've tried:

```
@client.command()
async def sendemoji(ctx):
    emoji = client.get_emoji(946753004365815878)
    await ctx.send(f'{emoji}')
```

The result was "None"

Comment: Your bot can only see and use emojis from guilds that the bot is in, this is why `get_emoji` returns `None` in your case. This is a discord limitation unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot needs to be in the server you are trying to pull the emoji from. If it's a large server that you aren't the owner of or can't add your bot too, you can probably find the emoji online and add it to one of your own servers. From there, you can add your bot to that server and then use the emoji globally. Hope this helps!